# Recursive subroutine

Tags: raku, rakudo

Let's say I have a pool of packages a, b, c,... each package has name, version and dependencies.

In below code, **get-cand** sub takes a package and returns the candidates from the pool (along with their dependencies recursively).

so if it took package named **c**, and the pool has

Package c1:
name **c**, version **1**, dep **a** (any version) and **b** (version **1**)

Package c2:
name **c**, version **2**, dep **b** (version 2)

it will return the following data structure:

```
((c1 ((((a1 ()) (a2 ()))) (((b1 ()))))) (c2 ((((b2 ()))))))  # can't figure out how to get rid of empty lists here
```

I'm trying to write **select-cand** sub that will take the above data structure and the goal is to return the first candidate that doesn't conflict (with installed packages), and recursively check it's dependencies as well.

so the sub should work like this:

- Check **c1**, if conflicts returned False, take **c1** and descend to it's deps
- (now in c1 deps) Check **a1**, if conflicts returned True, check next candidate (**a2**)

eventually it should return [c1 a2 b1] or [c2 b2] for successful run or nothing if all candidates conflicts.

but at the moment **select-cand** sub returns: [c1 a1 a2 c2 b2] which is wrong, because I only need either c1 (and it's deps recursively) or c2.

(**conflicts** is a place holder sub, at the moment it just  exclude b1 package for testing purpose)

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl6

my %pkgs;

class Pkg {
  has         $.name;
  has Version $.version = Version.new;
    has Pkg     @.dep;

    method Str {
      $!name ~ $!version;
    }
}

my $a1 = Pkg.new: name => 'a', version => Version.new: <1>;
my $a2 = Pkg.new: name => 'a', version => Version.new: <2>;
my $b1 = Pkg.new: name => 'b', version => Version.new: <1>;
my $b2 = Pkg.new: name => 'b', version => Version.new: <2>;
my $c1 = Pkg.new: name => 'c', version => Version.new: <1>;
my $c2 = Pkg.new: name => 'c', version => Version.new: <2>;

$c1.dep.push: Pkg.new(name => 'a');
$c1.dep.push: Pkg.new(name => 'b', version => Version.new: <1>);

$c2.dep.push: Pkg.new(name => 'b', version => Version.new: <2>);

%pkgs<a> .push: $a1, $a2;
%pkgs<b> .push: $b1, $b2;
%pkgs<c> .push: $c1, $c2;


sub return-pkg (Pkg $pkg) {
  my @pkgs = flat %pkgs{$pkg.name};
    return grep {$_.version ~~ $pkg.version}, @pkgs;
}  

sub get-cand (Pkg $pkg) {
    gather {
        take return-pkg($pkg).map( -> $pkg {
            ($pkg, $pkg.dep.map( -> $pkg {
                get-cand($pkg).Slip
            }).Slip)
        }).cache;
    }
}

sub conflicts (Pkg $pkg) {
  return True if $pkg.name eq <a> and $pkg.version eq <1>; 
  #take $pkg.Str if $pkg.name eq <a> and $pkg.version eq <1>; 
}

multi select-cand (Pkg $pkg) {
  return $pkg.Str if not conflicts $pkg;
}

multi select-cand (@cand) {
  gather {
    @cand.map({ .first({ take select-cand $_ })});
    }
}

my $c = Pkg.new: name => 'c';

my @cand =  get-cand $c;
my @selected = select-cand @cand;

say @selected; # [(c1 () (a2) (b1))]
```

Comment: You can return a [Slip](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Slip) which will flatten into an outer list. `sub foo () { |( 4, 5 ) }; (1,2,3,foo) eqv (1,2,3,4,5)`

Comment: Thanks  Brad Gilbert  and  raiph, I used Slip to flatten the empty lists to the outer container, I also rewrote select-cand sub as multi (updated in original question)

Comment: the datastructure looks like :
((c1 ((a1) (a2)) ((b1))) (c2 ((b2))))
I think I'm close, I will keep trying, but will appreciate any thoughts.
and the desired result is either: [c1 a1 a2] or [c1 a2 b1] or [c2 b2]